# Not able to import mapbox-gl npm package and cordova-plugin-mapbox

Tags: javascript, cordova, ember.js, mapbox-gl

How to import mapbox-gl npm package in cordova application?

```
const mapboxgl1 = require('mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js');

mapboxgl1.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibGF2by1jYWN0aW1lZGlhIiwiYSI6ImNqNGU3bjhsZzBrbHoycW1rZWxod290ZHYifQ.xof4oeDjbexECuTyqdkewQ';
  const map = new mapboxgl1.Map({
  container: 'map-test',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v10'
});
```

This is giving an error as -

Uncaught Error: Could not find module `mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js` imported from `(require)`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can directly use an external library with a cordova application like this. I would highly recommend you to use a cordova plugin. Have you tried using [this plugin](https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/Mapbox)?